# Square Root of $5$ mod $10^{9}+7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, modules, square-numbers

**$My$ $Current$ $Knowledge:$** We can find it if 5 is a $Quadratic$ $residue$ modulo p and where p is prime and we can check it using $Euler$ $criterion$.
I cannot able to find the root(5)mod 1000000007. Since 10^9+7 is prime we will able to find its solution.

Comment: Isn't that simply going to be root 5

Comment: @bulbasaur No. There exist a Quadratic residue solution ...Check this link for more detail [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is from an active competition https://www.codechef.com/APRIL16/problems/FIBQ

Comment: @lulu Sir, Even if it is related to some active contest, i am not asking about the solution of contest problem. I am just asking problem that i am facing.

Comment: Obviously, this is a critical part of that question.  It has appeared multiple times here over the past few days. No one here should respond to it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is no solution because the Jacobi/Legendre symbol is $(5 | 10^9+7)=-1$. With $p=10^9+7$ you compute $5^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv -1 \pmod p.$

Using the law of quadratic reciprocity,  $5 \equiv 1 \pmod 4,\;$ and the
other properties the Jacobi/Legendre symbol
$$\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{5}\right)=\left(\frac{p\bmod 5}{5}\right)= \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)=-1
$$